# JavaFX Enable and disable elements from outside

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to access my Main Stage from outside.
My mainstage is loaded with a fxml.
After that I can press a login button on the mainstage and then a login popup opens.
I want to set the button to Visi... as long as the login window is open. and then set it to Visi... afterwards.
Furthermore I want to show several elements in the mainstage after my login was successful.

```
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
   {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resource/views/lobbyMain.fxml"));
       primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 700));
       primaryStage.show();
       primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> {
           Platform.exit();
           if (loginStage != null){
               loginStage.close();
           }
           if (registrationStage != null){
               registrationStage.close();
           }
       });
   }
```

I hope you can help me in this regard.
Thank you very much.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/51050736#51050736)